# How to draw underline in textblock Windows Phone 8.1 Universal app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Hi i want underling like 
[image: here] how can i add underline like this in Windows Phone 8.1 universal app

I have tried the below solution but seems that it dosent work on wp8.1

```
<Border BorderBrush="DeepSkyBlue" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
    <!-- your text -->
</Border>
```

Comment: <Style x:Key="Underlined">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
        </Style>

this wont work in wp 8.1

Comment: getting error - member is not recognised or not accessable